# Python- unable to install modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently having an issue with downloading modules for Python. At first, it was a problem of directing Python to Path (which I later did), then it was an issue of the module I wanted to install not having the .py, now it is an issue of downloading setuptools.

I downloaded the setuptools here and extracted it to my desktop:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
Afterwards, I cd in cmd and tried a wide variation of ways of install this and I'm completely exhausted. I would greatly appreciate the help.
This is the error:

[image]

Please explain it as simple as possible to be as I'm a beginner and really need my hands held to get this done. I have been trying to find the solution to this problem for roughly 8 hours and decided it would be best to get the advice of experts.

Comment: You need to install the module `six`. If you have pip, just type `pip install six`.

Comment: There's an option to install pip (and setuptools) in the installer, so there's no reason for you to manually install setuptools. At most you may need to upgrade pip via `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `setuptools`. Within it's directory you should run `python setup.py install`, and it will be installed with any requirements it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're installing setuptools manually. I have never done this. See [installing packages guide](https://packaging.python.org/installing/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel)

> If you have Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 installed from python.org, you will already have pip and setuptools, but will need to upgrade to the latest version:

Instructions follow. They look pretty comprehensive. Good luck.